# How insert Male and Female symbol?

Tags: symbols

I use :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
```

I would like insert Male and Female symbols in my report,
I have tried with `\usepackage{marvosym}` but that is not working :

> LaTeX Error: Command \EUR already defined.

Could you help me ?

Comment: what do you mean when you mention *not working*? Can you complete your example such that it becomes a full example with problematic symbol macros? (off-topic you don't need to include evvery package here for a specific question)

Comment: I second percusse's comment: please discard everything that is not essential to explaining your question. People will understand much faster what you're getting at if you remove the clutter. The following works for me: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\Male \quad \Female
\end{document}`.

Comment: That is working with
    \usepackage{wasysym} and \male and \female without capital letters

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) lets you draw the symbol then gives you a set of possible matches. From that site, maybe this would work for you?

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
    \mars%
    \female%
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you’re using `wasysym`, you should use `\male` instead of `\mars`. Even if their output is the same (which I don’t know), there’s no reason not to use the semantically logical `\male` next to `\female`.